# as3 dynamic button name capturing problem

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

i am using this code below to dynamically capture the name of the button pressed and then playing the related balloon movie clip animation.

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, player); 

function player(evt:MouseEvent){
var nameofballoon = evt.target.name;
 nameofballoon =nameofballoon.substring(nameofballoon.length-1,nameofballoon.length);
var movie = "balloon"+nameofballoon;
 trace(movie);
movie.gotoAndPlay("burst");

  }
```

i'm getting this error even though the name of the clip capture by the event is correct

```
TypeError: Error #1006: value is not a function.
at Balloons2_fla::MainTimeline/player()
```

any thoughts ? what wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `movie` is considered as a String.
You should try something like this :

```
var movie:MovieClip = this["balloon"+nameofballoon];
movie.gotoAndPlay("burst");
```

You may have to replace `this` by the name of the parent of your `ballonX` MovieClip.

Answer (score 0):

```
var movie = "balloon"+nameofballoon;
trace(movie);
movie.gotoAndPlay("burst");
```

`movie` is a string - there is no `gotoAndPlay` method in `String` class.

Use

```
var movie:MovieClip = this.getChildByName("balloon"+nameofballoon);
movie.gotoAndPlay("burst");
```

Comment: I ran into a similar problem. Your solution helped me, but I did have to cast the movie specifically as movieclip. Like this: var movie:MovieClip = this.getChildByName("balloon"+nameofballoon) as MovieClip;